# Fortran: Open, form='(un)formatted', read

Tags: file-io, import, format, fortran

My data ('location_data.txt') look like :

```
100030002001000   39.772158  -75.527002         40  
100030002001001   39.771498  -75.525601         150  
100030002001002   39.771226  -75.526509         2  
100030002001003   39.767265  -75.526035         0  
100030002001004   39.769209  -75.527356         1  
100030002001005   39.769644  -75.528116         0  
100030002001006   39.767594  -75.527571         3  
100030002001007   39.770331  -75.530489         0  
100030002001008   39.769329  -75.529616         230  
100030002001009   39.768497  -75.528902         0  
100030002001010   39.769968  -75.524596         3  
100030002001011   39.769757  -75.525916         0  
100030002001012   39.768603  -75.525462         5  
100030002001013   39.768216  -75.524161         0  
100030002001014   39.768765  -75.522921         0  
100030002001015   39.767254  -75.524572         77  
100030002001016   39.767773  -75.523119         2  
100030002001017    39.76735  -75.522105         0  
100030002001018   39.768074  -75.521028         12  
100030002001019   39.766908  -75.521198         0
```

The variables are

1. unique key (len=15),
2. longitude
3. latitude
4. the number of workers.

My goal here is to get the four vectors from the external data. I am writing a Fortran code as follows:

```
program location

implicit none

integer, parameter :: maxnr = 200000
integer :: nr, i, j, ios
character(len=1) :: junkfornr

! My variable declaration
character(len=15), dimension(:), allocatable :: key
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: lat, lon
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: jobs

! Determine the total number of lines in my data file
nr=0
open(10, file='location_data.txt', status='old', form='formatted')
do i=1,maxnr
    read(10,*,iostat=ios) junkfornr
    if (ios/=0) exit
    if (i == maxnr) then
        write(*,*) "Error: Sorry, max. # of records exceeded..."
        stop
    endif
    nr = nr + 1
end do

print*, "The number of rows of the data =", nr

! Create variables: key, lat, lon, jobs
allocate(key(nr))
allocate(lat(nr))
allocate(lon(nr))
allocate(jobs(nr))

! Read variables from the data file
do i=1,nr
    read(10,*) key(i), lat(i), lon(i), jobs(i)
end do

print*, key

close(10)

end program location
```

---

If I use **form='formatted'** in the open statement, I've got the following message on the screen:

```
The number of rows of the data =                 20
At line 41 of file location.f90 <unit=10, file = 'location_data.txt'>
Fortran runtime error: Sequential READ or WRITE not allowed after EOF market,
possibly use REWIND or BACKSPACE
```

And when I change **form='formatted'** to **form='unformatted'**, I have another erroneous result:

```
 The number of rows of the data =                 0
```

I have several barriers to tackle in order to get to the solution for a bigger data analysis in Fortran, and I think now it's the time to seek some help from you Fortran gurus. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `form=unformatted` part of the `open` statement and it got through that part no problem.

I received a different error after fixing the above. After allocating the variables, you try reading from the file *without rewinding it*. That is, the program last left the file at at the end, so there isn't anything more to read when you try to read it. The fix is simple: tell the program to jump back up to the beginning by using `rewind`:

```
allocate(jobs(nr))
rewind(10)
do i=1,nr
   read(10,*) ...
enddo
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be fine if I add rewind(10) after enddo?

Comment: Kyle, it works! I thought that I found the number of lines of my data file, i.e., nr, so looping through i=1 to nr should work. I don't understand what the rewind statement really does.

Comment: Think of it like video cassettes. In order to watch the movie a second time, you have to rewind it. Likewise, in order to read the data (after it was read), you need to `rewind` it.

Comment: *Think of it like video cassettes.*  Oh you fortunate children, think of magnetic tapes used for data storage.  Still used in many big data shops too.