# Fortran: Unknown array size (Counting elements of an array)

Tags: arrays, fortran

This is a follow-up question from [Fortran: Open, form='(un)formatted', read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919729/fortran-open-form-unformatted-read). I have to create an array that saves the number of elements under certain criteria.

```
program location
implicit none
interface
    function distkm(deglat1,deglon1,deglat2,deglon2)
    real :: distkm
    real, intent(in) :: deglat1,deglon1,deglat2,deglon2
    end function distkm
end interface
integer, parameter :: maxnr = 200000
integer :: nr, i, j, ios
character(len=1) :: junkfornr
real :: start, finish
! My variable declaration
character(len=15), dimension(:), allocatable :: key
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: lat, lon
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: jobs
! Secondary arrays
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: jobs_within
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: sum_jobs
! Determine total number of lines in file
nr=0
open(10, file='location_data2.txt', status='old')
do i=1,maxnr
    read(10,*,iostat=ios) junkfornr
    if (ios/=0) exit
    if (i == maxnr) then
        stop
    endif
    nr = nr + 1
end do
! Create variables: key, lat, lon, jobs
allocate(key(nr))
allocate(lat(nr))
allocate(lon(nr))
allocate(jobs(nr))
allocate(jobs_within(nr))
allocate(sum_jobs(nr))
rewind(10)
do i=1,nr
    read(10,*) key(i), lat(i), lon(i), jobs(i)
end do
do i=1,nr
    do j=1,nr
        if (distkm(lat(i),lon(i),lat(j),lon(j)) <= 0.3) then
            jobs_within(j) = jobs(j)
        else
            jobs_within(j) = 0
        end if  
    end do
    sum_jobs(i) = sum(jobs_within)
end do
close(10)
open(20,file='key_sum_jobs_0.3.txt')
do i=1,nr
    write(20,100) key(i), sum_jobs(i)
end do
100 format(A15,I6)
end program location
```

The do loops save the sum of workers within 0.3 kilometers for each firm. Here, for each firm, the number of firms within 0.3 kilometers varies. How can I create an array (say, `n_neighbor`) that records the number of adjacent firms for each firm?

**EDIT:**
I believe the following solves the problem:

```
do i=1,nr
    n_aux(1:nr) = 0
    do j=1,nr
        if (distkm(lat(i),lon(i),lat(j),lon(j)) <= 1) then
            jobs_within(j) = jobs(j)
            n_aux(j) = n_aux(j) + 1
        else
            jobs_within(j) = 0
        end if
    end do
    write(20,100) key(i), sum(jobs_within), sum(n_aux)
    100 format(A15,I8,1X,I3)
end do
```

I create an integer array (`n_aux`). Then, the output text file of `unit=20` saves three columns: (1) firm key, (2) sum of workers within 0.3km, and (3) the number of firms within 0.3km.

**Things to ponder:**
I set all the elements of `n_aux` be `0` ahead of the `j` loop. Then, I throw `1's` where the `if` condition holds. Should there be other way to express this operation from the perspective of something like...dynamically assigning values onto an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is slightly inefficient in the double do-loop. Suppose you have only 5 firms, then your loop will count them as

> (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)
>
> (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)
>
> (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5)
>
> (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5)
>
> (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5)

You probably don't want to compute the distance from location 1 to location 1 since it'll be 0 as it is the same firm. You probably also don't want to count `(2,1)` since you've already done the work for `(1,2)`. What you can do instead is

```
do i=1,nr
   do j=i+1,nr
      ...
   enddo
enddo
```

However, if you do want to count `(1,2)` *and* `(2,1)`, you'd have to do

```
do i=1,nr
   do j=1,nr
      if(j == i) cycle
      ...
   enddo
enddo
```

which will skip `j=i` and go to `j=i+1`.

---

As to your actual question, I would think a 1D array, i.e. `allocate(n_neighbor(nr))`, is what you need. If we consider adjacent to be within that same 0.3 km, then you could do

```
if(distkm(lat(i), lon(i), lat(j), lon(j)) <= 0.3) then
   jobs_within(j) = jobs(j)
   n_neighbors(j) = n_neighbors(j) + 1
else
   jobs_within(j) = 0
endif
```

where we have initialized `n_neighbors=0`.

Though I don't quite understand the context of your problem, it seems to me that the index of `jobs_within` ought to be `i` and not `j` and that you probably want to sum them, i.e. `jobs_within(i) = jobs_within(i) + jobs(j)`. If this is not the case, feel free to ignore the comment.

Comment: Dear Kyle. (1) I don't understand your mention: "we have initialized `n_neighbors=0`." How does the initialization work in that `n_neighbors` is an array? (2) I think I solved my problem by your idea: throw 1 if the condition is met. Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Bill: Fortran allows array mathematics, so n_neighbor=0 sets every element if the array to 0. It looks like your edit is more or less what I suggested.

Comment: Kyle: Now I got it about `n_neighbor=0`. And you're right. The update is just from your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you really want, but just guessing it sounds as if you can write something like:

```
n_neighbor(j)=jobs(j)
```

in your else part.
If you want a better answer, please take out all the unnecessary stuff of your code.And then sum it the same way as you did for jobs_within.

Comment: I thought it would be better if I show the context of my analysis. I will try minimizing my question next time. And, I don't think your answer solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok maybe I missunderstood your question. If you tell me why it's not solving the problem, I might be able to improve my answer.